# Does anyone know how I can get my widget to open a dialog with an input box?

Tags: android, dialog, popup, click, widget

At the moment I have a widget which, when the user clicks on it, opens a login screen. I want to skip this step so that the user can go straight to the functionality of the app. The way I have seen other apps do this is with pop-up dialogs that allow the user's to input without opening the entire activity.

How would I go about getting a dialog to pop-up when the user clicks something in the widget. At the moment I have the custom dialog class made (even though a normal dialog would do), and I have tried calling it just like a normal activity but at no surprise this didn't work.

Does anyone have any other ideas?

Here's the ouput when the error occurs (the black box is the package name):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really show a Dialog from the Widget. You should start an Activity, but it can be styled as dialog using `Theme.Dialog`.

Comment: I have my dialog class made just like other dialogs I have made before, and in the Manifiest file I have:

<activity android:name=".WidgetLoginDialog"  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />

It throws an error when I run it though:

"java.lang.InstantiationException"

Comment: Sorry, not when I run it. The Widget shows up fine. When I click the widget and it tries to show the Dialog, the error happens

Comment: post the stacktrace to the question, please.

Answer (score 1):

in manifest.xml....... activity android:name=".Activity" 
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" 
android:label="@string/app_name"

Comment: I have this done for my dialog class, but when it tries to show the dialog the error that I just posted in the original question shows. Have you got any more ideas? Thanks btw.

Comment: delete whole of dialogue class.. u don't need it.. just create activity with dialogues functionalities... and set this activities theme as mentioned above...

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying delete the dialog class and then make a dialog class?

That will just give the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1):

try doin this.. and another thing do not create dialogue class.. i mean do not extend Dialogue.. extend activity..`
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Add extends Activity {
   //code goes here..

}

and this is the manifest.xml`

```
 </activity>
     <activity android:name=".Add" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" android:label="@string/app_name">

    </activity>
```